# Call a function in emblem conditional statement

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, emblem.js

How can we call a function with parameters in emblem's conditional statement. Like I have a function:

```
priorExist: (prior) ->
      @get("priors").findBy("condition", prior)
```

But I get an error when I call it in emblem like this

```
if priorExist(name)
```

Is there any way to call above function in emblem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above Functionality can be achieved by using Ember Components Like this

## Component if-existing-prior-component.coffee/js

```
App.IfExistingPriorComponent = Ember.Component.extend(existingPrior: (->
  @get("param2").findBy("condition", @get("param1"))
).property("param1"))
```

## if-existing-prior Template

```
if existingPrior
  = yield
```

Then we can use above component for comparisons in our emblem like this:

```
if-existing-prior param1=name param2=priors
```

Where `priors = @get("priors")`